# What does class* mean in HTML5

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

In Twitter Bootstrap there's the following CSS class selector:

```
.show-grid [class*="span"] {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Does this apply `margin-bottom: 5px` to any `span` class after `show-grid`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[attr*=value]` is the sub-string [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) - its new in CSS 3 and is supported in IE 7+

What you posted will add 5px of bottom margin to an element that has a class *containing* the sub-string `span` and is also a descendant of an element with the class `.show-grid`

Comment: contains attribute? do you mean * ?

Answer (score 6):

CSS3 Specification: [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)

> `[att*=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
>   contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the
>   empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

And according to your question:

> Does it means that applies margin-bottom:5px to any span class after show-grid?

**No**, it applies `margin-bottom: 5px` to every element that is descendant to any element marked with `show-grid` class and which class contains `span`.